# Form condition from table without dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Get the license details that are going to expire before the given days of interval. There are two tables, one is the 'Licenses' which holds the licenses details and expiration date. Another table is 'IntervalDays' which holds the days.

[image]

We could write  the query as below if we hardcode the interval days, BUt how could we use the other table for where conditions. Note: we shouldn't use dynamic sql for the performance considertion, Appreciate it if somebody could help here at the earliest.

```
SELECT LicenceId
           FROM Licences lic                   
           WHERE  (CONVERT(DATE, vip.ExpirationDate) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(Day, 30, GETDATE()))
                      OR CONVERT(DATE, vip.ExpirationDate) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(Day, 15, GETDATE()))
                      OR CONVERT(DATE, vip.ExpirationDate) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(Day, 7, GETDATE()))
                      OR CONVERT(DATE, vip.ExpirationDate) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(Day, 3, GETDATE()))
                      OR CONVERT(DATE, vip.ExpirationDate) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(Day, 2, GETDATE()))
                      OR CONVERT(DATE, vip.ExpirationDate) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(Day, 1, GETDATE())))
```

Comment: Recommended reading: [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea?__=2103529736)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
    SELECT LicenceId
       FROM Licences lic                   
       WHERE CONVERT(DATE, vip.ExpirationDate) IN (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(Day, [day], GETDATE())) FROM IntervalDays)
```

Comment: Great thought Alex. Wonderful. Appreciated.